# Zoom level limited in my google map iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I use the following code to display a map center on the user's location:

```
...
// start off by default current position
AppManager *appManager = [AppManager sharedManager];
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center.latitude = [appManager.currentlatitude floatValue];
newRegion.center.longitude = [appManager.currentlongitude floatValue];
newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.06;
newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.06;
[self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
...
```

The thing is, I do not manage to decrease the zoom level enough when playing with "newRegion.span.latitudeDelta" and "newRegion.span.longitudeDelta" values. The zoom only show a zone of something like 30 kms wide when I'd like to have several hundreds.

For what I saw, a value of 0.06 for longitudeDelta should show 180 degre (half of the earth) (for a latitude 0), then for a latitude of 43, I think I should see more than 30 km.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` are in *degrees* so a value of 0.06 is a relatively small distance in km.  To show "half of the Earth", you'd have to set the `longitudeDelta` to 180.0.

If you know the distance (eg. in km) you want to show, it will be easier to use the `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` function instead of trying to do the conversion yourself:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter = 
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([appManager.currentlatitude floatValue], 
                               [appManager.currentlongitude floatValue]);

MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = 
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newCenter, 200000, 200000);
```

The last two parameters are `latitudinalMeters` and `longitudinalMeters` so the above example sets the span to 200 km x 200 km.

Remember the map view will then adjust the region as needed based on the map view's proportions and displayable zoom level.